# minibrowser (or popup) on Android>5 and facebook like

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like, android-5.0-lollipop

I am getting some problems between facebook and the microbrowser that Android>=5 (lollipop) pop ups when (for example... in my case) a user tries to connect to a open wifi, but its connection is limited. The problem I am experiencing is that, when I show the like box:

```
<div class="facebookOuter">
    <div class="facebookInner">
        <div id="fb-connect"
            class="fb-like" 
            data-width="245" 
            data-height="290" 
            data-href="https://www.facebook.com/THE_PAGE_ID" 
            data-layout="button_count" 
            data-action="like" 
            data-show-faces="true" 
            data-share="false"
            data-border-color="#F4F4F4"
            data-layout="box_count">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It shows correctly with other brosers (including the iOS´s minibrowser -for the same case-), but not for the Android´s where never shows if the users like the page (the button allways shows the facebook icon), and clicking it, this event doesn´t work:

```
FB.Event.subscribe("edge.create",function(url, html_element) {
        window.location="redirect.php";
    });
```

The screen goes blank.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does the page get liked when the Like button is tapped? Does the browser display a blank screen when loading some content from Facebook, or when loading redirect.php?

Comment: Hi @subeeshb No... the page doesn´t get the like, indeed, the button doesn´t show correctly if user likes or not the page when it is rendering (for example, if I like X page, and I am on this page, it must to show the button with a check mark... but doesn´t). And about the blank screen, we have two buttons: 1 the facebook like button and 2 a simple <a href="redirect.php" class="btn">I am fan</a>... this last button works fine.